# Web Font Links Fail to Work on Github Pages but Work Locally

Tags: html, fonts, github-pages, font-face, cdn

I'm trying to use two web fonts, Bahnschrift and Blanka Regular on my Github Pages site. I'm using CDN Importing in my `<head>`.
I have the Blanka font working locally, but when exported the github, it stops working. I deleted Blanka from my system to check if the font is actually working.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/blanka" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding-left: auto; padding-right: auto;">
  <div style="font-family: Blanka;">IS THIS BLANKA FONT WORKING????</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This gives the result (which is what I'm looking for)
[Case1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBhi4.png)

However, when pushed to git, the github pages updates and gives this result
[Case2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVoZu.png)

I've heard somewhere that absolute links dont work, but when Imported my ttf files in the directory, they still don't show up in the Inspect Element section.

Is there a way I could make my custom fonts work on GitHub Pages? Thanks

Comment: Change `http://fonts.cdnfonts.com` to `https://fonts.cdnfonts.com` and try again if it work.

Comment: If i do that, it stops working locally. EDIT: wait mb had an error. it works locally

Comment: Your link to `http://`, if you open it directly in the address bar it will be redirect to `https://` anyway. Then change it to `https://`. Next, open network inspector and reload the page to see what is the result of this CSS URL.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to add `@font-face` in main css file
[You can read about @font-face here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

Comment: `@font-face` is already in the [CSS URL](https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/blanka) if you open it.

Comment: The problem was in the link :)

Comment: This could be a comment instead of an answer